# Not able to add object in sql database with extbase / typo3

Tags: typo3, extbase

I building my fist extension in typo3 6.2 with the extentions builder but i'm not able to add any record to the database. I'm reading an XML file and want to put the Ad data in the database. The problem is that notting is happening, no error and no record added in the database. Does anyone have a idee on what i'm doing wrong?

AdsController

```
class AdsController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

     public function insertAdByXML($xml) {

        $ad = new \MTR\Mtclnt\Domain\Model\Ads();
        $ad->setExtId((int) $xml->ad->ad_id);
        $ad->setAdCustId((int) $xml->customer_id);

        $this->adsRepository->add($ad);

        print_r($ad);
    }
}
```

Output print_r

```
MTR\Mtclnt\Domain\Model\Ads Object
(
    [extId:protected] => 438
    [adCustId:protected] => 17605
    [adCatId:protected] => 
    [adStatus:protected] => 0
    [adBrand:protected] => 
    [adType:protected] => 
    [adYear:protected] => 
    [adHours:protected] => 
    [adWeight:protected] => 
    [adStateNl:protected] => 
    [adStateEn:protected] => 
    [adStateDe:protected] => 
    [adPrice:protected] => 
    [adCurrency:protected] => 
    [adPriceTypeNl:protected] => 
    [adPriceTypeEn:protected] => 
    [adPriceTypeDe:protected] => 
    [adCusRef:protected] => 
    [adMovie:protected] => 
    [adSpotlight:protected] => 
    [adCarrouselImage:protected] => 
    [adOptionsNl:protected] => 
    [adOptionsEn:protected] => 
    [adOptionsDe:protected] => 
    [adDescNl:protected] => 
    [adDescEn:protected] => 
    [adDescDe:protected] => 
    [uid:protected] => 
    [_localizedUid:protected] => 
    [_languageUid:protected] => 
    [_versionedUid:protected] => 
    [pid:protected] => 
    [_isClone:TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject:private] => 
    [_cleanProperties:TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

AdsRepository

```
class AdsRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

}
```

TCA

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads'] = array(
    'ctrl' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads']['ctrl'],
    'interface' => array(
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, ext_id, ad_cust_id, ad_cat_id, ad_status, ad_brand, ad_type, ad_year, ad_hours, ad_weight, ad_state_nl, ad_state_en, ad_state_de, ad_price, ad_currency, ad_price_type_nl, ad_price_type_en, ad_price_type_de, ad_cus_ref, ad_movie, ad_spotlight, ad_carrousel_image, ad_options_nl, ad_options_en, ad_options_de, ad_desc_nl, ad_desc_en, ad_desc_de',
    ),
    'types' => array(
        '1' => array('showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden;;1, ext_id, ad_cust_id, ad_cat_id, ad_status, ad_brand, ad_type, ad_year, ad_hours, ad_weight, ad_state_nl, ad_state_en, ad_state_de, ad_price, ad_currency, ad_price_type_nl, ad_price_type_en, ad_price_type_de, ad_cus_ref, ad_movie, ad_spotlight, ad_carrousel_image, ad_options_nl, ad_options_en, ad_options_de, ad_desc_nl, ad_desc_en, ad_desc_de, --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'),
    ),
    'palettes' => array(
        '1' => array('showitem' => ''),
    ),
    'columns' => array(

        'sys_language_uid' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'sys_language',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY sys_language.title',
                'items' => array(
                    array('LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages', -1),
                    array('LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.default_value', 0)
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'l10n_parent' => array(
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'items' => array(
                    array('', 0),
                ),
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
            ),
        ),
        'l10n_diffsource' => array(
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ),
        ),

        't3ver_label' => array(
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'max' => 255,
            )
        ),

        'hidden' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hidden',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'check',
            ),
        ),
        'starttime' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 13,
                'max' => 20,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'checkbox' => 0,
                'default' => 0,
                'range' => array(
                    'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'endtime' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 13,
                'max' => 20,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'checkbox' => 0,
                'default' => 0,
                'range' => array(
                    'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'ext_id' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ext_id',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 4,
                'eval' => 'int'
            )
        ),
        'ad_cust_id' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_cust_id',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_cat_id' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_cat_id',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_status' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_status',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 4,
                'eval' => 'int'
            )
        ),
        'ad_brand' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_brand',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_type' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_type',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_year' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_year',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_hours' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_hours',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_weight' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_weight',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_state_nl' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_state_nl',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_state_en' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_state_en',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_state_de' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_state_de',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_price' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_price',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_currency' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_currency',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_price_type_nl' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_price_type_nl',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_price_type_en' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_price_type_en',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_price_type_de' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_price_type_de',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_cus_ref' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_cus_ref',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_movie' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_movie',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_spotlight' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_spotlight',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_carrousel_image' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_carrousel_image',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_options_nl' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_options_nl',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_options_en' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_options_en',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_options_de' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_options_de',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_desc_nl' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_desc_nl',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_desc_en' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_desc_en',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),
        'ad_desc_de' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:mtclnt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_mtclnt_domain_model_ads.ad_desc_de',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ),
        ),

    ),
);
```

Adsmodel

```
class Ads extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * extId
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $extId = 0;

    /**
     * adCustId
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adCustId = '';

    /**
     * adCatId
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adCatId = '';

    /**
     * adStatus
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $adStatus = 0;

    /**
     * adBrand
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adBrand = '';

    /**
     * adType
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adType = '';

    /**
     * adYear
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adYear = '';

    /**
     * adHours
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adHours = '';

    /**
     * adWeight
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adWeight = '';

    /**
     * adStateNl
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adStateNl = '';

    /**
     * adStateEn
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adStateEn = '';

    /**
     * adStateDe
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adStateDe = '';

    /**
     * adPrice
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adPrice = '';

    /**
     * adCurrency
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adCurrency = '';

    /**
     * adPriceTypeNl
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adPriceTypeNl = '';

    /**
     * adPriceTypeEn
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adPriceTypeEn = '';

    /**
     * adPriceTypeDe
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adPriceTypeDe = '';

    /**
     * adCusRef
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adCusRef = '';

    /**
     * adMovie
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adMovie = '';

    /**
     * adSpotlight
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adSpotlight = '';

    /**
     * adCarrouselImage
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adCarrouselImage = '';

    /**
     * adOptionsNl
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adOptionsNl = '';

    /**
     * adOptionsEn
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adOptionsEn = '';

    /**
     * adOptionsDe
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adOptionsDe = '';

    /**
     * adDescNl
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adDescNl = '';

    /**
     * adDescEn
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adDescEn = '';

    /**
     * adDescDe
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $adDescDe = '';

    /**
     * Returns the adBrand
     *
     * @return string $adBrand
     */
    public function getAdBrand() {
        return $this->adBrand;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adBrand
     *
     * @param string $adBrand
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdBrand($adBrand) {
        $this->adBrand = $adBrand;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adType
     *
     * @return string adType
     */
    public function getAdType() {
        return $this->adType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adType
     *
     * @param string $adType
     * @return string adType
     */
    public function setAdType($adType) {
        $this->adType = $adType;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the extId
     *
     * @return integer $extId
     */
    public function getExtId() {
        return $this->extId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the extId
     *
     * @param integer $extId
     * @return void
     */
    public function setExtId($extId) {
        $this->extId = $extId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adStatus
     *
     * @return integer $adStatus
     */
    public function getAdStatus() {
        return $this->adStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adStatus
     *
     * @param integer $adStatus
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdStatus($adStatus) {
        $this->adStatus = $adStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adYear
     *
     * @return string $adYear
     */
    public function getAdYear() {
        return $this->adYear;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adYear
     *
     * @param string $adYear
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdYear($adYear) {
        $this->adYear = $adYear;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adHours
     *
     * @return string $adHours
     */
    public function getAdHours() {
        return $this->adHours;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adHours
     *
     * @param string $adHours
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdHours($adHours) {
        $this->adHours = $adHours;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adWeight
     *
     * @return string $adWeight
     */
    public function getAdWeight() {
        return $this->adWeight;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adWeight
     *
     * @param string $adWeight
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdWeight($adWeight) {
        $this->adWeight = $adWeight;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adStateNl
     *
     * @return string $adStateNl
     */
    public function getAdStateNl() {
        return $this->adStateNl;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adStateNl
     *
     * @param string $adStateNl
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdStateNl($adStateNl) {
        $this->adStateNl = $adStateNl;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adStateEn
     *
     * @return string $adStateEn
     */
    public function getAdStateEn() {
        return $this->adStateEn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adStateEn
     *
     * @param string $adStateEn
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdStateEn($adStateEn) {
        $this->adStateEn = $adStateEn;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adStateDe
     *
     * @return string $adStateDe
     */
    public function getAdStateDe() {
        return $this->adStateDe;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adStateDe
     *
     * @param string $adStateDe
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdStateDe($adStateDe) {
        $this->adStateDe = $adStateDe;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adPrice
     *
     * @return string $adPrice
     */
    public function getAdPrice() {
        return $this->adPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adPrice
     *
     * @param string $adPrice
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdPrice($adPrice) {
        $this->adPrice = $adPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adCurrency
     *
     * @return string $adCurrency
     */
    public function getAdCurrency() {
        return $this->adCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adCurrency
     *
     * @param string $adCurrency
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdCurrency($adCurrency) {
        $this->adCurrency = $adCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adPriceTypeNl
     *
     * @return string $adPriceTypeNl
     */
    public function getAdPriceTypeNl() {
        return $this->adPriceTypeNl;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adPriceTypeNl
     *
     * @param string $adPriceTypeNl
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdPriceTypeNl($adPriceTypeNl) {
        $this->adPriceTypeNl = $adPriceTypeNl;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adPriceTypeEn
     *
     * @return string $adPriceTypeEn
     */
    public function getAdPriceTypeEn() {
        return $this->adPriceTypeEn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adPriceTypeEn
     *
     * @param string $adPriceTypeEn
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdPriceTypeEn($adPriceTypeEn) {
        $this->adPriceTypeEn = $adPriceTypeEn;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adPriceTypeDe
     *
     * @return string $adPriceTypeDe
     */
    public function getAdPriceTypeDe() {
        return $this->adPriceTypeDe;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adPriceTypeDe
     *
     * @param string $adPriceTypeDe
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdPriceTypeDe($adPriceTypeDe) {
        $this->adPriceTypeDe = $adPriceTypeDe;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adCusRef
     *
     * @return string $adCusRef
     */
    public function getAdCusRef() {
        return $this->adCusRef;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adCusRef
     *
     * @param string $adCusRef
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdCusRef($adCusRef) {
        $this->adCusRef = $adCusRef;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adMovie
     *
     * @return string $adMovie
     */
    public function getAdMovie() {
        return $this->adMovie;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adMovie
     *
     * @param string $adMovie
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdMovie($adMovie) {
        $this->adMovie = $adMovie;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adSpotlight
     *
     * @return string $adSpotlight
     */
    public function getAdSpotlight() {
        return $this->adSpotlight;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adSpotlight
     *
     * @param string $adSpotlight
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdSpotlight($adSpotlight) {
        $this->adSpotlight = $adSpotlight;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adCarrousselImage
     *
     * @return boolean $adCarrousselImage
     */
    public function getAdCarrousselImage() {
        return $this->adCarrousselImage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adCarrousselImage
     *
     * @param boolean $adCarrousselImage
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdCarrousselImage($adCarrousselImage) {
        $this->adCarrousselImage = $adCarrousselImage;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the boolean state of adCarrousselImage
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAdCarrousselImage() {
        return $this->adCarrousselImage;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adOptionsNl
     *
     * @return string $adOptionsNl
     */
    public function getAdOptionsNl() {
        return $this->adOptionsNl;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adOptionsNl
     *
     * @param string $adOptionsNl
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdOptionsNl($adOptionsNl) {
        $this->adOptionsNl = $adOptionsNl;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adOptionsEn
     *
     * @return string $adOptionsEn
     */
    public function getAdOptionsEn() {
        return $this->adOptionsEn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adOptionsEn
     *
     * @param string $adOptionsEn
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdOptionsEn($adOptionsEn) {
        $this->adOptionsEn = $adOptionsEn;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adOptionsDe
     *
     * @return string $adOptionsDe
     */
    public function getAdOptionsDe() {
        return $this->adOptionsDe;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adOptionsDe
     *
     * @param string $adOptionsDe
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdOptionsDe($adOptionsDe) {
        $this->adOptionsDe = $adOptionsDe;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adDescNl
     *
     * @return string $adDescNl
     */
    public function getAdDescNl() {
        return $this->adDescNl;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adDescNl
     *
     * @param string $adDescNl
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdDescNl($adDescNl) {
        $this->adDescNl = $adDescNl;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adDescEn
     *
     * @return string $adDescEn
     */
    public function getAdDescEn() {
        return $this->adDescEn;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adDescEn
     *
     * @param string $adDescEn
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdDescEn($adDescEn) {
        $this->adDescEn = $adDescEn;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adDescDe
     *
     * @return string $adDescDe
     */
    public function getAdDescDe() {
        return $this->adDescDe;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adDescDe
     *
     * @param string $adDescDe
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdDescDe($adDescDe) {
        $this->adDescDe = $adDescDe;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adCatId
     *
     * @return string $adCatId
     */
    public function getAdCatId() {
        return $this->adCatId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adCatId
     *
     * @param string $adCatId
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdCatId($adCatId) {
        $this->adCatId = $adCatId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the adCustId
     *
     * @return string $adCustId
     */
    public function getAdCustId() {
        return $this->adCustId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adCustId
     *
     * @param string $adCustId
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdCustId($adCustId) {
        $this->adCustId = $adCustId;
    }

    /**
     * __construct
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initStorageObjects();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
     * Do not modify this method!
     * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
     * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initStorageObjects() {

    }

    /**
     * Returns the adUsed
     *
     * @return string $adUsed
     */
    public function getAdUsed() {
        return $this->adUsed;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the adUsed
     *
     * @param string $adUsed
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAdUsed($adUsed) {
        $this->adUsed = $adUsed;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you activate the development preset in install tool? You may get some errors after activating. Also note, that database actions are not performed after calling ``->add`` but after the underlying action has finished.

Comment: The development preset is active but no errors. What do you mean with the underlying action has finished? How can I make sure it is finished?

Comment: How does the ads-model look, especially the annotations?

Comment: I have added the Adsmodel. Can you have a look at the annotations?

Comment: @Merec Looks like the problem is that the persistencemanager is not called. When I add the following code to the controller behind the add stated it works. `$persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Manager'); 
  $persistenceManager->persistAll();`  But why is the persistencemanager not called automatically after the add function?

Comment: Because the persistence manager is only called at the end of the action to avoid unnecessary overhead. If you want to persist in the middle of your actions, then please call the persistence manager yourself.

Comment: @pgampe I understand but what determine the end of the actions? In my case the only action after the add is the print_r action. But the persistence manager sees this somehow not as the last action?

Comment: "action" is not just more "code", we mean the action-method in your main controller e.g. ``doMyStruffAction()``